# Servicio Rest de tipo post Login ¿Qué falta para mejorarlo?

Tags: java, mysql

```
@Override
public Usuarios Login(Usuarios usuarios) {

    try {
        String sql = "SELECT id_cliente, email, nivel FROM USUARIOS  WHERE email= ? and contraseña = ? ";
        PreparedStatement preparedStatement = cx.prepareStatement(sql);
        preparedStatement.setString(1 , usuarios.getEmail());
        preparedStatement.setString(2, usuarios.getContrasena());
        ResultSet rs = preparedStatement.executeQuery();
        if (rs.next()) {
            usuarios = new Usuarios(rs.getInt("id_cliente"),
            rs.getString("email"),
            rs.getString("nivel"));
            usuarios.setUservalido(true);
        }else {
            usuarios.setUservalido(false);
        }
        rs.close();
        preparedStatement.close();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        System.out.println(e.getMessage());
    }
    return usuarios;
}
```

Cuando ingreso el email y contraseña correctas me devuelve lo que deseo pero cuaando no es el caso

```
{
    "contrasena": "1234s",
    "email": "user",
    "id_cliente": 0,
    "uservalido": false
}
```

Eso me devuelve cuando pruebo el servicio, quisiera añadir un mensaje diciendo que es incorrecto.

Answer (score 0):

1.- podrías agregar un nuevo atributo (String mensaje) al objeto Usuarios y cuando el usuario no se encuentre en base de datos, le seteas un mensaje al atributo mensaje.

2.-  algun programa o algo debe estar llamando al rest supongo un jsp o html, en este caso validar si el atributo userValido == fase, mostrar un mensaje por pantalla.

saludos, te recomiendo usar algun framework de persistencia de base de datos.

Answer (score 0):

Puedes usar la clase JOptionPane.

```
import javax.swing.JOptionPane;

public class HelloWorld {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "Hello World");
    }
}
```